# How to set cookies in get requests headers in python

Tags: python-2.7, header, python-requests, http-headers, request-headers

I am trying to do a GET request call to a local internal portal to fetch data from the portal. I am able to do it successfully using the below code. But i am hard coding the 'cookie' parameter in the request header which might change in the future. If i am not giving the cookies in header im getting a 403 response. Is there anyway to do the GET call without hardcoding the 'cookie' header?

PS - i am headers which are mentioned in the 'Request Headers' in the developer tools of chrome in the code below.the request headers in chrome developer tools :

```
GET /api/router/service/instance-33/api/monitoring/metrics/summary?timeline=10m&metricGroupType=Client HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: xxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1166979480.1557148769; _rollup=GA1.2.1925782236.1557148769; _gid=GA1.2.572392410.1560761227; VIDUSR=1560762756-eXdFaeT29yEDoA%3d%3d
```

Code im using :

```
import requests

url = 'xxx'
proxies = {
  'xxx/',
  'xxx',
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1166979480.1557148769; _rollup=GA1.2.1925782236.1557148769; _gid=GA1.2.572392410.1560761227; VIDUSR=1560762756-eXdFaeT29yEDoA%3d%3d', 'Host': 'xxx', 'Referer': 'xxx', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, verify=False, headers=headers)

print(r.json())
print(r)
```

Comment: I found the answer. Instead of giving cookie details in the header, just give the username and password and do an auth in the GET request.